# Interpreting Regression coefficients where Y is an index

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, predictor

I am having trouble with the correct interpretation of my regression coefficients. My independent variable is fund allocation which is a continuous variable. I have two output variables on which I regress separately.

1. I construct an index for infrastructure by combining the normalised value of the number of schools and hospitals and averaging across the two. The coefficient is 0.079. Can I say 1 unit increase in funds causes a 7.9% increase in my index for infrastructure.
2. Similarly I have another index for sanitation where I average across two variables (both binary). The coefficient is 0.037. So can I say a unit increase in funds causes a 3.9% increase in my sanitation index?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing "regular" OLS regression then it's not a percentage increase, but a numeric one. That is 1 point increase in fund allocation is associated with a 0.079 point increase in the infrastructure index.

Percent increases would be from a logistic regression.

And you can't say "causes" as this is an observational study. You can only say "associated with" or similar, non-causal terms.